# Retrieving the mousemove handler in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Is there any way to retrieve the current mouse move handler for a selection in jQuery?

The normal method, as per standard jQuery, would be to simply call `$('selector').mousemove()`, but I see that for the events this simulates the event instead of returning the handler.

Is this possible?

Comment: are you looking for something like `var handlers = $._data($(selector)[0], 'events').mousemove;` see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/75fAn/1/

Comment: @ArunPJohny That looks exactly like what I'm after - could you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you are after are the mousemove handlers attached to an element, in that case you can use a non-documented method `jQuery._data()` like

```
var handlers = $._data($('div')[0], 'events').mousemove;
```

here `handlers` will be an array of objects where each object refer to a handler for `mousemove` event. from the object you can get the handler method using the `handler` property.

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/NVzP4/)

Answer (score 1):

try like this

```
<div id="target">Move here</div>
<div id="other">Trigger the handler</div>
<div id="log"></div>
```

jquery

```
$( "#target" ).mousemove(function( event ) {
  var msg = "Handler for .mousemove() called at ";
  msg += event.pageX + ", " + event.pageY;
  $( "#log" ).append( "<div>" + msg + "</div>" );
});
```

API reference [jQuery mousemove](http://api.jquery.com/mousemove/)

Comment: This is setting up a handler - I'm trying to retrieve a reference to an existing handler.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set handler function to mousemove()

```
$(document).mousemove(function(event){
  console.log(event.pageX + ", " + event.pageY);
});
```

For your example is:

```
$(document).mousemove(handlerfunction);

function handlerfunction(event){
    console.log(event.pageX + ", " + event.pageY);
}
```

Comment: This is setting up a handler - I'm trying to retrieve a reference to an existing handler.

Comment: `Use $(document).mousemove(handlerfunction); `